# Can't understand the solution of the secretary problem

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

The solution of the no information version is very simple to understand. But I can't understand the solution of the full information version.

I am reading the book "[*Algorithms to live by*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25666050-algorithms-to-live-by)" (Brian Christian & Tom Griffiths, $2016$) and by the book it goes something like this:

> Each candidate has a rating which indicates her percentile. So if we have $2$ candidates for example and the first candidate has a rating of $60$, it means she has $60\%$ chance to be better than the second candidate.

In the case of only $2$ candidates it is obvious that we will choose the first one if she has a rating of more than $50$; but in the book it says that we will choose the third from last candidate if she has more than $69$ rating and we will choose the fourth from last candidate of she has at more than $78$ rating.

How did they calculate this?

Comment: Why one earth do you assume we have the slightest idea "the secretary problem" is and we have any idea what you are talking about?  I've you have a question about a problem, you should include the problem in your question.  That is only common sense.

Comment: I think he's referring to a variant of the problem in this numberphile video. https://youtu.be/ZWib5olGbQ0

Comment: It's okay, I googled it, but in general if you ask a question... include the question.

Comment: Even googling it these specific numbers 60, 69 and 78 and third from last and fourth from last all refer to a specific telling of the problem and it is absurd to assume we all have this particular book in front of us and are going to look this problem up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments that you need to actually state the problem. But the answer I got matches so I guess the objective is as in the usual secretary problem where you get 1 point for selecting the best candidate and zero if you select anyone else. Furthermore the secretaries' fitnesses are independent from some distribution you know and when you interview you can observe their quantile.

To determine whether to continue, you need to determine whether your expected points from selecting the candidate is larger than your expected points if you continue.

Say three candidates for simplicity and say the first has percentile $\alpha.$ The expected points if you select the candidate is easy. It is just the probability that they are the the best which is $\alpha^2.$

The continuation value is a little trickier. If the second is better than the first, you will accept them with 100% probability, there is an $1-\alpha$ chance of this. You will get a point unless the third is the best of all three. If $\beta>a$ is the percentile of the second there is a probability $\beta$ chance the third is worse so averaging over this gives a success probability of $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_\alpha^1 \beta d\beta = (1+\alpha)/2$

If the second is worse than the first you will reject them (since then your only hope for getting the best is that the third is the best). Then the probability of the third being better is $1-\alpha.$

So the continuation expected value is $$ (1-\alpha)\frac{(1+\alpha)}{2} + \alpha(1-\alpha).$$

Setting the continuation value equal to the value for stopping gives $$\alpha^2 = (1-\alpha)\frac{(1+\alpha)}{2} + \alpha(1-\alpha) $$ or $$ \alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{6}}{5} \approx .69.$$

I would add that in the general case you wouldn't necessarily choose the third-from-last candidate if they had above $69.$ Only if they had it *and* they were the best so far. Otherwise you need to skip them in order to have any chance at the best. This will be important in setting up the recursion for the general case.

Comment: My apologize for not fully explaining the problem. In the normal secretary problem, you would choose the second candidate if she is better than the first one, because the first one is your baseline. Here you don't need a baseline, because each candidate has a rating which tells you how is she in compare to others. So if you don't choose the first one you will choose the second one only if she has a rating above 50 (50% rating to be better than the third and last one in case of 3 candidates). I guess that the answer is a^x>0.5 x = number of candidates left. But how do i isolate a?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Second out of what? If I'm reading/interpreting your equation right you are saying to decide yes when the probability that the candidate is the best of the three is greater than 50%. That would give $a^2=.5$ You isolate $a$ by taking the square root of both sides and get $a=(.5)^{1/2} \approx .707$. This is close as is the answer $(.5)^{1/3}\approx .793$ for four candidates. The reason these are a bit too high is you're not taking into account the fact that you might not select the best candidate even if they are later.